# How to parse a string that contains value only needed partially to an arraylist?

Tags: java, regex

I have a string that looks like this:

`String a = "name:string, age:int, address:string,city:string, zip:int";`

The string is separated by `,` and between `:` it is the `fieldName` and `type`. There might be space between each value but any space should be ignored.

What I want is to convert this string into an arrayList that only contents `fieldName`.

So the above example will become

`List<String> result = new ArrayList<>;` and in the result there should be values of `name, age, address, city, zip`. Everything else should be ignored.

How do i do this with regex in Java?

I can achieve this by first do the split by `,` then split the string array by `:`, and take the first element of the array then added to a list.

The reason i m asking is because I want to know if there is a more elegant way to do this with regex.

Comment: Can someone comment why the downvote?

Comment: @Andreas i added what i have tried in the description. The whole reason to ask this is to check if i can do it in one step instead of multiple

Comment: That's not how the original question read. It read as "I want this, tell me how to do it". --- You still don't **show** the *code* of what you have tried. Don't explain the code, show it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String[] b = a.split(":[^,]+(?:, *)?");
```

Or:

```
String[] b = Pattern.compile("[^, ]+(?=:)").matcher(a).results()
                    .map(r -> r.group()).toArray(String[]::new);
```

Comment: @OPK [Reference - What does this regex mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22937618/5221149)

Answer (score 0):

The following regex will give you the results you want

```
[a-z]+[^, ](?=:)
```

The first parentheses is called a look ahead, so anything that is before a : will be selected, the first set of brackets says we want any character a-z (note these are case sensitive so add +[A-Z] if caps may be used), the final set of brackets says no , or space

to use this in java you would write something along the lines of

```
Pattern.compile("[a-z]+[^, ](?=:)")
       .matcher(a)
       .find();
```

I use [this site](https://regexr.com/) a lot to test regex's it's a really helpful tool

Comment: That will match all the types (`string, int, string, string, int`), but OP wants the names (`name, age, address, city, zip`).

Comment: Sorry I misread, I have updated my answer

Comment: i still don't think this works. just tested it.

Comment: What results are you getting with that? And where are you testing?

Comment: The code works now, but only if you use a regex `find()` loop, not if you use `split()`. Neither question **nor** answer shows how the regex is ***used***. Both question and answer are incomplete. `unspecific question + unspecific question = mass confusion`

Comment: That code does nothing.

Comment: Yeah I'm going to leave this one be lol, I added how I would use it in Java and hopefully that helps